# NetBeans and GDB from MinGW

Tags: c, netbeans, gdb, mingw, breakpoints

NetBeans 6.9.1, here is screenshot of imported MinGW utils:
[image]

When I'm trying to run debugger after setuping breakpoint this happens:
[image]
So NetBeans don't see breakpoints and there is no gdb log. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem still exists in Netbeans 8.1.

What seemed to work for me:

1) Open / create project.
2) Set a breakpoint and build debug binaries
3) Close and reopen project.